# Android Dev Kit in Eclipse

Tags: performance, eclipse, android, sdk

So I have a few issues with Eclipse and Android Dev Kit.

First of all Eclipse is being unbelievably slow and sometimes it renders it really useless. (It even lags switching the tabs!!!.)

I tried modifying the .ini file and tried allocating it even as much as 2gb-3gb ram. Still no improvement.

Is there any way to get it up to Visual Studio efficiency? When I'm debugging and I want to view a value inside a class in the watch it lags to display a simple 2 digit integer! Seriously W*F is up with that? VS instantineously displays 100s of objects in a collection with no lagging.

Also debugging is really slugish and it is really annoying! Steping from one line to another takes about 2 seconds!

My laptops has this spec:

```
Core i7-2670QM 2.2GHz (turbo up to 3.1GHz)
8GB DDR3 RAM
500GB HDD
GeForce GT630M 1GB (Dedicated)
```

This laptop handles some of the most demanding software and games without an issue and Eclipse lags!

Another issue, when I launch the Android Emulator my sound drops by around a half (for everything.) I use the internal sound card (integrated.) Any idea of how to fix it?

Thanks very much

Daniel Wardin

Comment: Has this always been like that? Have you tried changing to a new workspace, removing the Android Eclipse plugin entirely, etc?

Comment: "Need an answer ASAP" is not a good way of asking for help!

Comment: @slhck It's always been slugish but got worse today, no I haven't since I need it to do my work

Comment: I suggest using Procmon to see what is happening when the system is running slow. This will tell you what process is hogging up your resources and what it's doing (disk i/o, ram usage, etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue after deleting everything to do with Eclipse and installing the x86 version instead of the x64 and the performance is a LOT better now!

It must be a design fault in the IDE.